# Do I have to cast on every line?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I've been teaching myself programming from scratch by creating a simple app in Objective C. Today, I was faced with the issue that I had to write a method that didn't know what type of object it was going to get. With the help of Google, I was delighted to discover something called "casting". :)

I am using casting like so:

```
- (void)aCustomViewControllerNeedsToChangeStuff:(id)viewController
{
    ((SpecialViewController *)viewController).aProperty = somethingInteresting;
    ((SpecialViewController *)viewController).anotherProperty = somethingElse;
    ((SpecialViewController *)viewController).yetAnotherProperty = moreStuff;
}
```

Do I have to cast on every line like that, or is there a way I can cast "viewController" once in the scope of the method, to make my code neater?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can cast your controller to temp variable and use it (also added type check - just in case) :

```
- (void)aCustomViewControllerNeedsToChangeStuff:(id)viewController
{
    if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[SpecialViewController class]]){
        SpecialViewController *special = (SpecialViewController *)viewController;
        special.aProperty = somethingInteresting;
        special.anotherProperty = somethingElse;
        special.yetAnotherProperty = moreStuff;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
- (void)aCustomViewControllerNeedsToChangeStuff:(id)viewController
{
    SpecialViewController * controller = (SpecialViewController *)viewController;
    controller.aProperty = somethingInteresting;
    controller.anotherProperty = somethingElse;
    controller.yetAnotherProperty = moreStuff;
}
```

Comment: Well his answer is just better. :)

Answer (score 2):

Use one variable like

```
  SpecialViewController *tempController = (SpecialViewController *)viewController;
```

than use this variable to access value like

```
tempController.aProperty
```